# Modifying normal template

Tags: microsoft-word, macbook, templates

I am using Word for Mac v16.16, and I am operating under Yosemite (because I still use iPhoto). I have located the normal.dot template and I wish to modify it, but when I open it it won't let me. The styles are greyed out and it shows this funny little cursor. Is anyone able to advise please?

Comment: There isn't a Normal.dot named template. Maybe you made a typo. Needlessly though, you need to explain some about what you are attempting to do directly in the Normal template. There most likely are other ways, and more appropriate ways of setting default functioning of this critical template.

Comment: Go to /Users/username/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates, double-click the Normal.dotm, check if you can make changes. Or you can create a new blank document, make your wanted changes, then rename it to Normal.dotm to Desktop, cut the original Normal template to another place for backup. Then paste the new created Normal.dotm to that location.

Comment: Oh No @WinniL that is not the way to create a new Normal template. Word stores many processing controls in the Normal template.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am wanting to change the styles and cut down the styles gallery, in the normal template. I tried doing it within a Word document and saying add to default template but it doesn't work. In the past I used to simply edit the normal.dotx template (or whatever it's called) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the Styles Gallery that appears on the Home tab of the ribbon, Mac Word 2016 does not natively have a feature yet that allows you to edit this Quick Styles gallery.

As an alternative though you can use a free add-in that will provide that functionality. Do a web search on **AuthorTec Quick Styles** and read about it.